# Can I create a self-signed certificate for a local ip with a specific port?

Tags: https, openssl, ssl-certificate

I know I can't get an SSL certificate through public CA for a local IP.

But I have multiple web services what need HTTPS, and they are for use in the same network, so I created a CA (self-sign) and I was able to create a SSL certificate for a local ip (ex. 192.168.xxx.xxx). But I want to have different certificates for each web service (ex 192.168.xxx.xxx:8000, 192.168.xxx.xxx:8001, and so on).

When I tried to create that using "CN = 192.168.xxx.xxx:8001" with openssl, firefox shows: "ssl_error_bad_cert_domain"

Comment: You can use different certificates for different servers on different ports, and possibly the same server on different ports depending on the configuration of that server, but the cert itself can only be for the host name (or a wildcard covering the name) or address, not the port. Also note Chrome for years and Firefox since about 100 (last summer) accepts _only_ SubjectAltName _extension_ not CommonName _attribute_. But this is not programming or development and is offtopic.

Comment: Also PS: that's not self-signed. In PKI/X.509 self-signed means a cert signed with teh same key as is in the cert, and Subject name = Issuer name. A cert signed by your or my personal CA is signed by you or me but not self-signed.

Comment: On which port you run a server is not relevant for the certificate. It only contains the DNS name(s) and /or IP address(es) of the server.